# Minimum number of subgraphs such that every node is included?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a graph of N nodes, and we have S subgraphs of this original graph where each subgraph contains subset of the N nodes. It is guaranteed that each node exists in at least one subgraph.

We want to know the minimum number of subgraphs X out of S such that every node of the N nodes is included at least once in at least one subgraph of the chosen X subgraphs. Is there a way to do this with efficient complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an instance of the [Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). Set cover is NP-Hard, so there is unfortunately no way to efficiently solve this in general.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions in mind which dont require you to brute force through all possible combinations, one not being too perfect, the other being less efficient.
Like stated by SaiBot, a perfect and efficient answer doesn't seem to exist.

1. You could start once with every subgraph X and continue adding the graphs that contain the most missing nodes. Afterwards you could pick which solution needed the least subgraphs.
2. You could assing each subgraph X an "independecy" value, which describes how many of his nodes are not (or rarely) contained in other subgraphs as well and combine that with method one to get a possibly more perfect solution at the cost of generating this "independency" value.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, this is an NP-hard problem. If you like, you can approximate it to a factor of about ln(n) efficiently. This is as good an approximation factor as possible to achieve efficiently (assuming NP-hard problems are lower bound to exponential complexity).

You can do this with the [Greedy set cover algorithm](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F07/scribe-notes/lecture02.pdf). 
Basically, what the algorithm does is repeatedly selected the set (subgraph in your case) with most uncovered elements (verices). It repeats this until no more uncovered elements exist.